# using group by to fetch results

Tags: c#, mysql, group-by

I have two tables in my database :

```
song   => id, name, song_ref, views 
artist => id, name
```

I want to fetch all the artists from the song table with the most viewed song for each one. 
 
I've tried to use `MAX(views)` to get the max views value, but didn't succeed to get the other fields for this relevant song.

```
SELECT a.name, MAX(s.views) FROM song s inner join artist a 
ON s.artist_ref = a.idArtist GROUP BY a.name
```

any ideas ? thank you

Comment: Have you considered adding the desired columns to your SELECT clause?

Comment: yes , it will show a random result that not related to the max views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.id AS aid,
          a.name AS artist,
          s.id AS sid,
          s.name AS most_viewed,
          s.views
   FROM artist a
   INNER JOIN song s ON s.artist_ref=a.id
   ORDER BY a.id,
            s.views DESC) c
GROUP BY c.aid;
```

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was incorrect. Here's a revised version that works:

```
SELECT a.idArtist AS aid, a.name, s.id AS sid, s.views
FROM artist a INNER JOIN song s ON a.idArtist = s.artist_ref
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(views) AS views, artist_ref FROM song GROUP BY artist_ref) max_songs
ON s.artist_ref = max_songs.artist_ref AND s.views = max_songs.views
ORDER BY a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT a.name, 
(SELECT s.views FROM song s WHERE s.name=a.name 
ORDER BY s.views DESC LIMIT 0,1) as `views` 
FROM artist a
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fiddle return the correct values (Edited Fiddle link name and include working SQL statement that returns associated columns for the rows with most viewed songs).

[Link to Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c467cd/11)

It demonstrates the following SQL Statement with test data.

```
SELECT a.Name, a.songRef, Views, aName  FROM artist b 
INNER JOIN song a on a.Name = b.aName 
   WHERE Views = 
      (SELECT MAX(Views) from Song as z
         WHERE z.Name = b.aName) GROUP BY a.name, b.aName, a.songRef
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mrt Did you follow the link to the fiddle and determine it is off base or was the fact that the hyperlink text was "GROUP BY Example with MAX(Views)", which could easily be interpreted as a worthless SQL statement. The answer has been edited.

Comment: Sure I did. Anyway, now that you edited your answer my complaint is no longer valid. ;)